# write stored proc for the two queries, truncating and inserting two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two queries below. how do i put them in one stored proc. both the queries are truncating and inserting records in two different tables.

QUERY 1

truncate table [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps] 
go

INSERT INTO [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]

```
(Ndc, AwpUnitCost) 

SELECT DISTINCT P.Ndc Ndc, A.Price AwpUnitCost 

FROM 

    PlanFinder.PlanFinder.HpmsFormulary P 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Ndc, Price FROM MHSQL01D.Drug.FdbPricing.vNdcPrices  

               WHERE PriceTypeCode = '01' AND CurrentFlag = 1) A 

ON P.Ndc = A.Ndc  

WHERE (A.Ndc IS NULL OR A.Price <= 0 OR A.Price IS NULL) 

AND p.Ndc IS NOT NULL
```

---

Query 2

truncate table [PlanFinder].[MissingNdcs]
go

INSERT INTO [PlanFinder].[MissingNdcs]

```
(Ndc) 

SELECT DISTINCT Ndc 

FROM 

    PlanFinder.InvalidAwps   

WHERE AwpUnitCost IS NULL
```

Thanks and Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take out the `GO` statements and dump all the code in 1 proc

```
create procedure prBla
as

truncate table [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps] 

INSERT INTO [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps](Ndc, AwpUnitCost) 

SELECT DISTINCT P.Ndc Ndc, A.Price AwpUnitCost 
FROM 
    PlanFinder.PlanFinder.HpmsFormulary P 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Ndc, Price FROM MHSQL01D.Drug.FdbPricing.vNdcPrices  
               WHERE PriceTypeCode = '01' AND CurrentFlag = 1) A 
ON P.Ndc = A.Ndc  
WHERE (A.Ndc IS NULL OR A.Price <= 0 OR A.Price IS NULL) 
AND p.Ndc IS NOT NULL

truncate table [PlanFinder].[MissingNdcs] 
INSERT INTO [PlanFinder].[MissingNdcs] (Ndc) 

SELECT DISTINCT Ndc 
FROM  PlanFinder.InvalidAwps   
WHERE AwpUnitCost IS NULL  
GO
```

you might want to add some error handling...what do you want to do...rollback all if one of the statements fails or not?

Comment: ohh, so i just had to take out GO, thats y i was getting an error. thanks appreciate it.

Comment: to clarify and/or explain: go ends a block of sql statements and submits it for execution. This is not needed in a stored procedure, since it is and has to be a single block of code. The go needs to be after the end of the create procedure statement and not inside it.

Comment: DOn't forget Denis's question about error handling and rollback, this is critically important when you insert into more than one table. YOu need to have this is a transaction that rolls back if part of it fails.